# Adding percentage values onto horizontal bar charts in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts, enumerate

My pandas dataset, df4, consists of 14 Colour Groups (Green, Blue etc) and 12 Categories (1, 2 etc). I am creating a horizontal bar chart for each category.

```
print(df4.head())
 BASE VOLUME Color Group  Type
0        6.0       GREEN  1
1        3.5       GREEN  1
2        2.5       GREEN  2
3        1.5       GREEN  2
4        2.5       BLUE   4
```

Here is the code below, with how the graph looks for 2 of the categories. On some of the categories, the percentages are all vertically lined up, but on others the percentages are wild.

```
#groupby / pivot transformation, and reindex
s='1'
dfrr = df4[df4['Type'] == s]
df5 = dfrr.groupby(['Color Group']).sum().sort_values("BASE VOLUME", ascending=False)
data = df5.reset_index().iloc[:,[0,2]]
data.columns = ['Color Group', 'BASE VOLUME']
x= data['BASE VOLUME']
y= data['Color Group']

data2 = data
data2['BASE VOLUME %'] = data2['BASE VOLUME']
data2 = data2.iloc[:,[0,2]]
data2['BASE VOLUME %'] = 100*data2['BASE VOLUME %']/(sum(data2['BASE VOLUME %']))

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))

clrs = ['red' if (x > 10) else 'gray' for x in data2['BASE VOLUME %']]
ax = sns.barplot(x,y, data=data2, palette=clrs)
ax.set_xlabel('Base Volume',fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Color Group',fontsize=15)
plt.xticks(fontsize=15)
plt.yticks(fontsize=15)

for i, v in enumerate(data2['BASE VOLUME %']):
    ax.text(v + 0, i + 0.15, str("{0:.1f}%".format(v)), color='black', fontweight='bold', fontsize=14)
```

For Category 1, the percentages are lined up:
[image]

For Category 4, the percentages are not lined up:
[image: Not lined up]

The problem may be that there are only 7 colour groups in Category 4, compared to all 14 in Category 1. How can I tweak the code so that whatever I set as 's' (i.e the category), the percentages line up?

Comment: Where do you want your labels to appear? At the bar tips? At the bar bottom?

Comment: I would like the bars to appear as in the first image - i.e. on 0 on the x axis.

Comment: Ok that seems easy: replace `ax.text(v + 0, ...` by `ax.text(0, ...`

Comment: Wow, as simple as that! Many thanks.